# writing to element.style.visibility has no effect on page ( same IDs have different addresses? )

Tags: javascript

I of course verified that element exists.

I've even verified that you can read that element value.

But as far as the output to the page there is no effect ( the element does not become visible ).

```
// debug verificatoin
alert('debug on: domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility: ' + domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility );

// write action 
domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Here is the code...it works on the first run..but after that fails..it is a logic issue in the javaScript I believe...this is old code..and had a weird style.

```
var domMenu = 
{
    TIME_DELAY:             1000,
    time_out_id:            0,
    drop_down_element:      0,
    top_mouse_over:  function ( id ) 
    {
        if( !domMenu.drop_down_element )
        {
            domMenu.drop_down_element = document.getElementById( 'wrap_drop_down_new' );
            domMenu.top_element = document.getElementById( 'top_new' );
        }
        clearTimeout( domMenu.time_out_id );
        domMenu.show_menu();
    },
    bottom_mouse_over: function() 
    {
        clearTimeout( domMenu.time_out_id );
    },
    mouse_out: function()
    {
        domMenu.time_out_id = setTimeout( domMenu.hide_menu, domMenu.TIME_DELAY );
    },
    hide_menu:function()
    {
        domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        domMenu.top_element.style.border = '1px solid #faf7f7';
    },
    show_menu:function()
    {    
alert('debug on: domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility: ' + domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility );
        domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility = 'visible';
        domMenu.top_element.style.border = '1px solid #cfcaca';
        domMenu.top_element.style.borderBottom = '3px solid #cfcaca';
    }
};
```

**Answer**

This was an issue with state so I just kept pulling the menu elements.  This is a hack fix to an issue I don't understand.

```
var domMenu = 
{
    TIME_DELAY:             1000,
    time_out_id:            0,
    drop_down_element:      0,
    top_mouse_over:  function ( id ) 
    {
        domMenu.drop_down_element = document.getElementById( 'wrap_drop_down_new' );
        domMenu.top_element = document.getElementById( 'top_new' );

        clearTimeout( domMenu.time_out_id );
        domMenu.show_menu();
    },
    bottom_mouse_over: function() 
    {
        clearTimeout( domMenu.time_out_id );
    },
    mouse_out: function()
    {
        domMenu.time_out_id = setTimeout( domMenu.hide_menu, domMenu.TIME_DELAY );
    },
    hide_menu:function()
    {
        domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        domMenu.top_element.style.border = '1px solid #faf7f7';
    },
    show_menu:function()
    {    
        // alert('debug on: domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility: ' + domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility );
        domMenu.drop_down_element.style.visibility = 'visible';
        domMenu.top_element.style.border = '1px solid #cfcaca';
        domMenu.top_element.style.borderBottom = '3px solid #cfcaca';
    }
};
```

Comment: What were you using? IE, Chrome, other soft? Give a bit more details

Comment: Without seeing your markup and CSS, it's ***extremely*** hard to help you solve this problem. I've spitballed a few options, but really, you need to be much more detailed.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info...it is a logic issue..I'm posting the code now...it works on a reload...but not afterwards.

Comment: Is it the visibility property that fails after the first time, or the whole script? Does it throw the alert every time?

Comment: I ended up just removing the if statement...I have no idea what happened here...I just went to a site with 0 reloads..pure ajax..and this was the last issue...I fixed the issue by removing the if statement...I have no idea why this fixed the issue or how I guessed that this was a "state" issue and that by grabbing the static id repeatedly would some how fix the issue...I will repost the answer. thanks be to luck.

Comment: I think that on a body.innerHTMl write..the actual reference to the node changes...even though it has the same ID...That is same ID different reference internally...so I need to grab it again...better yet put the id pull in the initialization and pass it in. it is good to not that you can have two elements with the same ID from different points in time....but different internal references....or addresses I'm guessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the element does not become visible

Barring your showing us your markup and CSS, the only things I can think of are:

1. It has an ancestor element that is invisible (either `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`)
2. It has `display: none`.
3. It's off the page. (Or at least, it's outside of any visible box; if its parent or other ancestor has `overflow: hidden` and it's positioned outside the dimensions of that parent/ancestor...)
4. It has no dimensions (e.g., both width and height are zero), so it's visible, you just can't see it.
5. Michael Sazonov points out that its parent (or other ancestor) could have `opacity: 0`. (Or the element itself could have it.)

Comment: Also if the parent element has opacity 0

Comment: I believe it is a logic issue in the javascript as it works on the first run...but not after...I've posted above..thanks for this info. as well...and sorry again for the lack of info...I had NO idea what the issue was and what to post.

Answer (score 0):

As for your last comment - that explains everything. Once you use `getElementById` - the browser retrieves an element by its ID, but refers it as a DOM object. Therefore, after grabbing the element, the ID has no meaning anymore. Once that DOM element deleted - browser looses its reference, so you need to grab it again (by any method you find the best). About `innerHTML` - if you don't want to track and grab every DOM element again and again - you better not rewrite via `innerHTML`. Better use `element.appensChild()` function. It addes element to the parent element without rewriting its `innerHTML`.